# Compile Groovy with Maven and Eclipse compiler: How to ignore unknown @SuppressWarnings?

Tags: eclipse, maven, groovy

I have a Maven project for our Groovy code using the following:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
      <configuration>
        <source>${source.version}</source>
        <target>${source.version}</target>
        <verbose>false</verbose>
        <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
        <compilerArguments>
          <indy />
        </compilerArguments>
      </configuration>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
          <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
          <version>${groovy-eclipse-compiler.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
          <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
          <version>${groovy-eclipse-batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
          <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
          <version>${groovy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
          <artifactId>groovy-json</artifactId>
          <version>${groovy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
          <artifactId>groovy-templates</artifactId>
          <version>${groovy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
          <artifactId>groovy-xml</artifactId>
          <version>${groovy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
          <artifactId>groovy-json</artifactId>
          <version>${groovy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
          <artifactId>groovy-templates</artifactId>
          <version>${groovy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

(The Maven properties are set elsewhere)

Now we're using [CodeNarc](https://codenarc.github.io/CodeNarc/), which sometimes gives false positives. To suppress those, we use `@SuppressWarnings`, for instance `@SuppressWarnings('GStringExpressionWithinString')` , which in return leads the Eclipse compiler to show warnings:

```
15:12:29.671 [WARNING] C:\groovy\src\main\groovy\Util.groovy:[472,19] 
7. WARNING in C:\groovy\src\main\groovy\Util.groovy (at line 472)
  @SuppressWarnings('GStringExpressionWithinString')
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Can anyone tell me how I can configure the Eclipse compiler to stop showing these warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the compiler option `-warn:-warningToken` would disable warnings for unused @SuppressWarnings tokens.

https://help.eclipse.org/2020-03/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_batch_compiler.htm

https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki/Groovy-Eclipse-Maven-plugin

```
  <configuration>
    <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
    <compilerArguments>
      <indy />
      <warn:-warningToken />
    </compilerArguments>
  </configuration>
```

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArguments

Otherwise you can switch to using `<compilerArgs>` which gives more control over each argument string.

```
  <configuration>
    <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
    <compilerArgs>
      <arg>-indy</arg>
      <arg>-warn:-warningToken</arg>
    </compilerArgs>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks! The first link is dead, however. I tried the Eclipse help, which uses http://127.0.0.1:51207/help/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_batch_compiler.htm   Also, I couldn't pass the option to work within `compilerArguments` : Do you have a working example?

Comment: If you use the compilerArguments element, Maven adds dash in front of element name and equals between name and value.  So "<warn>-warningToken</warn>" would translate to "-warn=-warningToken" on the command line.  Not what you want.  Looks like you can try "<warn:-warningToken />"  within <compilerArguments>. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArgs

Comment: Thanks a lot, that nailed it!